# please add option to have an item in the "experience" section show expanded state on stack careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

On my careers.stackoverflow profile, I would like one the items listed in my "Experience" section to default to the expanded state. Please add an option for this.
Maybe it could be added in the "display options" menu while editing.

Comment: I 1000% agree on this!!